# Internal redirect with Google Global external HTTP(S) load balancer (classic)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, load-balancing

I am using Google Cloud. I have 2 backend services and one Google storage Bucket. For certain cases I would like to define the logic for when to direct to a Google Storage bucket and I want it to be transparent to the user.

For example:

- I have backendService1 urlmapping as https://example.com/backendService1
- I have backendService2 urlmapping as https://example.com/backendService2
- And I have the Google Cloud Storage bucket under: https://example.com/bucket

What I would like to achieve is based on some custom logic in my backendService1, send the user to https://example.com/bucket/abc if he visits https://example.com/backendService1/abc more than x number of times while the URL still looks like https://example.com/backendService1/abc

This is similar to just its within GCP backends and buckets using google External loadbalance
https://serverfault.com/questions/524731/http-reverse-proxy-redirect-internally

Is there some way to set headers or status to achieve this via a load balancer internal redirect?

Comment: You want to redirect the user to the bucket url if the user visits backendservice1 “N” number of times. Correct me if I am wrong. Do you have any such plans about service2 ? Did you try by referring to the given [server fault link](https://serverfault.com/questions/524731/http-reverse-proxy-redirect-internally)? If yes, can you share that code?

Comment: I am not using ngnix for this. I wan to achieve this in google load balancer for now I am letting service1 handle this by reading from bucket and sending a plain response after N visits. Could not find any such functionality within Google Load Balancer.

Comment: If the answer was useful, please upvote or mark the answer as accepted for greater visibility for community members.

Answer (score 0):

[URL redirection](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map-concepts#url-redirects) is the procedure used to redirect domain's visitors from one URL to another.But achieving the expected output is infeasible using cloud as it involves customer architecture(tracking the customer via cookies and storing it in our system) and Cloud Support is not equipped to plan customer architecture.